# execfile not defined in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and repairing google app engine to no avail.

here's the log

```
2017-02-02 20:22:42 Running command: "['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python35-32\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=11080', '--admin_port=8003', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\code\\engineapp']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 89, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 85, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
2017-02-02 20:22:42 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\pythonw.exe'

You seem to be running Python 3, which is not supported by the GAE standard env.

You need to switch to Python 2.7 instead.